# Return value in non-function Javascript code block

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

I'm trying to work out what's going on in Mike Bostock's Box Plot example from the D3 gallery. Here's the code inside an Observable notebook: https://observablehq.com/@d3/box-plot

In it there's a code block that does not appear to be a function definition but that has a return value:

```js
chart = {
    const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(width, height));

    const g = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(bins)
        .join("g");

    // [...]

    return svg.node();
}
```

What does `return` do or mean when it is not in a function definition?

Comment: If I remember, one time I read how ES6 or something with Babel allows returns outside of functions.

Comment: I believe it's just the way observablehq does it, more information here -> https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-code  IOW: Its just a simple custom transpiler they have created, it's not standard JS.

Comment: That's not a common JS block, that's a function. As the observable's intro says, *"To understand reactivity, think of each cell as a function. For example, the cell sum = a + b becomes a function that takes a and b as arguments, returning their sum;"*. And then: *"Cells come in two primary forms: expressions and blocks [...] Blocks are surrounded by curly braces, { and }, and are intended for more complex definitions"*.

Comment: Funnily enough, that's the second time this week that someone asks about that *"strange block"* returning something in Observable. I'm not comfortable writing an answer because I really don't think that this Q/A pair is a fit for S.O., but if the trend continues I reckon that a formal answer would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to here. Looks like the trend did continue, and the answer is difficult to search. It bothered me for a week and with no luck finding any answer and I end up asking a similar question.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, as the commenters have suggested, this is a syntax that's particular to Observable. What you're seeing a cell that uses a block, as [mentioned in the Introduction to Code](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-code).

How you can think of this relative to other JavaScript is that it's kind of like an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), but with the added consideration that, if it references other cells, it automatically resolves them. So in vanilla JavaScript, this would be like:

```js
chart = (() => {
    const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(width, height));

    const g = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(bins)
        .join("g");

    // [...]

    return svg.node();
})()
```

In fact, that's roughly what they compile to. The particular syntax is that way because it's meant to be clear that it's code that runs when references change - see [how Observable runs](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/how-observable-runs) for details on that. Unlike an IIFE, a cell in Observable might run multiple times, if something that it references, like a generator or Promise, changes.